# How to move db request (which uses yield) in an other function?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

I'm playing with tornado and mongodb, with the asynchronous driver motor.
When working with callbacks everything's fine. Then I discovered the possibility to use motor.Op or tornado.gen.Task to perform a request in one function only:

So this is working:

```
class Contact_handler(Main_handler):

    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, other_id):

        event = events.Event_send_contact_request(self.user_id)
        result = yield motor.Op(db.users.update,
                     {'_id': ObjectId(other_id)},
                     {'$push': {'evts': event.data}}
                    )

        self.finish("ok")
```

But I'd like to move this database request in its own function in another module. The problem is that I don't understand really how the yield is working here (despite I read a LOT of questions about yield).
So this is what I tried, but it's not working:

```
#------ file views.py -------------

class Contact_handler(Main_handler):

    def get(self, other_id):

        event = events.Event_send_contact_request(self.user_id)
        result = model.push_event_to_user(other_id, event)

        self.finish("ok")
```

And the call in another function:

```
#------ file model.py -------------

@gen.coroutine
def push_event_to_user(user_id, event):

    ## Ajout de la demande dans les events du demandé:
    yield motor.Op(db.users.update,
                     {'_id': ObjectId(user_id)},
                     {'$push': {'evts': event}}
                    )
```

If I investigate with pdb:

```
(Pdb) l
157             event = events.Event_send_contact_request(self.user_id)
158             result = model.push_event_to_user(other_id, event)
159             
160             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
161             
162  ->         self.finish("ok")
163         

(Pdb) result
<tornado.concurrent.TracebackFuture object at 0xa334b8c>
(Pdb) result.result()
*** Exception: DummyFuture does not support blocking for results
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another way of doing this, thanks to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/python-tornado/t9NOV4cXZs4) that uses of [tornado.gen.Return](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Return). I still need to yield in my main function, but the coroutine is simple.

Here is my code now:

```
#------ file views.py -------------

@web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
class Contact_handler(Main_handler):

    def get(self, other_id):

        event = events.Event_send_contact_request(self.user_id)
        result = yield model.push_event_to_user(other_id, event)

        self.finish("ok")
```

And the call in another function:

```
#------ file model.py -------------

@gen.coroutine
def push_event_to_user(user_id, event):

    ## Ajout de la demande dans les events du demandé:
    result = yield motor.Op(db.users.update,
                            {'_id': ObjectId(user_id)},
                            {'$push': {'evts': event}}
                           )
    raise gen.Return(result)
```